# What services do I need to use Experience Manager without Session Preview?

Tags: experience-manager

I'm using XPM without the Session Preview feature and it is working well.  We need to manually re-publish the content, but otherwise it is responsive and we intend to continue using it without Session Preview.  However, we initially configured it for Session Preview and now when setting up the next server, we'd like to set it up without Session Preview.

These are the original services and DB I had installed.  Do I still need any of these if I am **not using Session Preview**?

- SDL Web Session Preview Service
- Register the Preview Capability
- Session-Enabled Content Service (?)
- Session Preview DB

Is it possible to not install any of the Session Preview pieces and still have XPM functionality?  Or, is the XPM functionality embedded within Session Preview services and code?

And what configuration is responsible on the front-end to translate the XPM tags into showing the XPM ribbon and the editing features?

Is it only the modules?

```
<add name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule"
             type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule"/>
        <add name="PreviewContentModule" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.PreviewContentModule"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you turn of Session Preview, XPM behaves very much like SiteEdit (anyone remember SE?).
The XPM user interface, which actually runs on the CM side, will use the XPM tags in the markup of the preview site to do it's magic.
No preview services, databases or front-end configuration is required as long as the front-end writes out the XPM tags.
This means in this configuration XPM will work fine with a traditional static HTML site where the XPM tags are rendered at publish time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the information provided by Jeroen... if you are not using Session Preview, then you **do not** need the following:

1. SDL Web Session Preview Service (as you won’t be using the fast tracked publishing needed for Session Preview)
2. Session-Enabled Content Service (The ‘normal’ Content Service will suffice)
3. Session Preview DB (as you won’t be storing temporary session updates)

Additionally, as you no longer need the Session Preview database, you will no longer need the additional configuration for this in your `cd_storage_conf.xml` file.